# Layer with custom UI not working properly

Tags: qgis, spatialite, widget

I have a problem with QGIS 2.4 when introducing layers with a custom UI. More precisely, widgets such as CheckBoxes are not recognised as such (appear as Text Edit in Attributes) and the corresponding Checked value appears as NULL (although checked by default in the UI file).

When I am manually changing the specific field:

```
instudy_id = layer.fieldNameIndex("instudy")
layer.setEditorWidgetV2(instudy_id, 'CheckBox')
```

Everything is normal. The corresponding part of the UI file is:

[image: UI file]

Sorry if my explanation is poor, I am quite new to QGIS. Hope the screenshots help.

[image: Layer -> Properties]
[image: Attribute Table of Layer]

To conclude:

- some options of my Widgets (defined in my .ui file) are overwritten by QGIS (e.g. "Checked" or "Unchecked" state of a QCheckBox)
- others, which are introduced in the corresponding .py file (like QgsEditorWidgetWrapper.fromWidget( in study ).setEnabled(False) ) are not respected by QGIS.

What is the proper way to introduce a custom / customise an .ui file ? Is there anywhere detailed information/examples on the use of newer methods like QgsVectorLayer.setEditorWidgetV2, setEditorWidgetV2Config, QgsEditorWidgetWrapper ?

Answer (score 2):

What is shown in the *layer properties* / *Fields* tab in the column *Edit widget* is not defined by the .ui file (like you seem to assume as you are saying "recognized"). Instead, it is a configuration that needs to match your .ui-file. You can open it and change the edit widget to **Check Box** and configure it to your needs.

To set these values with python you can use the following code:

```
layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(instudy_id, {u'CheckedState': 1, u'UncheckedState': 0} )
```

To actually set the value of the widget you can subsequently use the following code to set the value of the widget.

```
QgsEditorWidgetWrapper.fromWidget( instudy ).setValue( 1 )
```

The editable state of a widget needs also to be controlled by QGIS, as it needs to enable/disable widgets based on the layer editable state. Therefore there is a special method to tell QGIS which widgets should never be swichted to editable

```
layer.setFieldEditable( instudy_id, False )
```

For more information have a look at the API documentation in particular [QgsVectorLayer::setEditorWidgetV2](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a05a33f4d4f9953571f680f6b18589559)

More information about the widget wrapper can also be found [here](http://blog.vitu.ch/10142013-1847/write-your-own-qgis-form-elements)

Comment: Good to know that the "Edit Widget" column doesn't get any info from the .ui file. And yes, I know that I can change it manually. The thing is that it seems pointless to me. First of all, I can't afford to do this for every single layer I design. Then, what's the purpose of importing a custom UI if it is not taken into account properly (here the "in study" Checkbox is not checked as it was configured to be but I have other similar problems as well).

Comment: The point is, that you can configure things in QGIS that you are not able to configure in QtDesigner. E.g. the representation of True/False in the data cannot be configured in QtDesigner. Common representations are 1/0, T/F, t/f... You need to tell QGIS which one to use.

Comment: I see your point. But I am still a bit confused. Is this part then (in the .ui file):<property name="checked">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property> useless?

Comment: Pretty much. This is used for the default state (when used as a widget independent of any field) and will be overwritten by QGIS when used in combination with a field.

Comment: Furthermore, how come when I modify a QLineEdit feature like height_field.setText("0") it is not overwritten by QGIS, however instudy.setChecked(True) which is a QCheckBox is? Same goes for QComboBoxes. Why are these features different than QLineEdits?  And should I provide the default state (e.g. Checked=True) in the code (and please how) ?

Comment: You can directly call `setChecked()` as well. But the behavior of QGIS is undefined in this case. Instead you can use `QgsEditorWidgetWrapper.fromWidget( instudy ).setValue( 'T' )`.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I managed to do what I wanted by adding what you proposed in the python init function file. However, since my question was more about this last part, you could update your answer by adding this if you want.

Comment: Please bring your (original) question into an answerable state. I don't even see a question mark in there.

Comment: Please, any idea where I could find more info on the use of newer methods like QgsEditorWidgetWrapper, setEditorWidgetV2 and setEditorWidgetV2Config ?

Comment: Answer updated to contain additional links and information about editable.